# How to check if there exists a secondary selection?

Tags: secondary-selection

Emacs has a secondary selection (not the X11 selection, rather the `mouse-secondary-overlay`).

On my system holding Alt-LMB dragging sets it.

How would I check if there this selection is set in elisp?

I tried checking;

```
(if mouse-secondary-overlay
  ... do something ...)
```

however this always prints `"Have Second Select"`

How can this be tested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(gui-get-selection 'SECONDARY)
```

returns nil if there is no secondary selection. (if your Emacs is older than 25.1, use `x-get-selection` instead)

Comment: Minor detail, I don't want to get the actual text, just to know if a secondary selection exists.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by checking if the start of `(overlay-start mouse-secondary-overlay)` is not nil.

This is a function that uses the secondary selection, then the primary as a fallback.

```
(defun mouse-yank-secondary-and-deselect (click)
  "Deselect after yanking, for quick select-copy. Uses primary as fallback."
  (interactive "*p")
  (if (overlay-start mouse-secondary-overlay)
      (progn
        ;; use the secondary buffer and clear it
        (mouse-yank-secondary click)
        (delete-overlay mouse-secondary-overlay)
        )
    (progn
      ;; fallback to primary buffer
      (mouse-yank-primary click)
      )
    )
  )
```